# what 3- or 4- monitor, 2560x1600, video card works in seamless mode on virtualbox?

Tags: video, virtualbox, graphics-card, virtual-machine, display

I tried the [nVidia nvs450](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_nvs_450_us.html) and it leaves a trail when I move the window. Same with the [ATI FirePro V8800](http://www.amd.com/us/products/workstation/graphics/ati-firepro-3d/v8800/Pages/v8800.aspx). Anyone know of a cards that is **guaranteed** to work with this set-up? (As in - either you tried it yourself, or there's an article where it is explicitly shown to work. None of the "well it'll probably work", since that's what they said about the V8800.)

Comment: I've never used Virtualbox but I /have/ used a V8800 and if it doesn't work on that, your odds are a crapshoot with anything else.  That's like saying your Peterbilt won't tow your boat, so what else can you try to tow it with?  Sounds like a driver problem to me.